# How to hide "+" button from StickerPipe view in iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm using StickerPipe view to show custom emoji on my keyboard but the problem is that I need to remove + button from keyboard header but it is not hiding

```
var stickerController: STKStickerController = STKStickerController() 


STKStickersManager.setUserKey("23")
self.stickerController.hideSuggestCollectionView()
```

[image]

Comment: Its a custom library on github. If they have exposed a function for it, you can remove it, but it seems like they havent.
If you really want to do it, you will have to import the library in your code, and modify the code of the library to remove the plus sign.

Comment: Ok @KakshilShah will try to do that...